# MSBuild 15/16 FileNotFoundException in application on startup

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a tool that used the old MSBuild until now and finally gets an upgrade to MSBuild 15/16.
I've followed the guide in the documentation to change the references, since with MSBuild 15 onward these don't get installed to the GAC anymore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2019
I used the latest NuGet packages and configured everything as it should be. It builds fine, but whenever I run the program it immediately crashes complaining that the `"Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"` cannot be found.
It explicitly states in the guide above:

> > > If you redistribute Microsoft.Build.Locator.dll with your application, you won't need to distribute other MSBuild assemblies.

This happens before any code in `Main` is executed. If I try to copy this file to the output path via project settings, build will fail with a message saying this should not be done.

> > > A PackageReference to Microsoft.Build.* without ExcludeAssets="runtime" exists in your project. This will cause MSBuild assemblies to be copied to your output directory, causing your application to load them at runtime. To use the copy of MSBuild registered by MSBuildLocator, set ExcludeAssets="runtime" on the MSBuild PackageReferences. To disable this check, set the property DisableMSBuildAssemblyCopyCheck=true in your project file (not recommended as you must distributed all of MSBuild + associated toolset). Package(s) referenced: Microsoft.Build;Microsoft.Build.Framework;Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core

The project uses the following references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build">
  <Version>16.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework">
  <Version>16.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator">
  <Version>1.2.6</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core">
  <Version>16.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="NuGet.VisualStudio">
  <Version>5.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

If I omit any of the MSBuild ones, compilation will also fail because of missing references. Compilation itself is done in a differenct class in a background task.

```
...
logger = new ControlLogger();
logger.LogEvent += new ControlLogger.LogEventHandler(ControlLogEventHandler);
logger.Verbosity = Verbosity;
logger.LogToFile = true;
logger.Parameters = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "Logs", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) + ".txt");
BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
bp.Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { logger };
BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName), globalProperty, null, new string[] { Target }, null);
return new Tuple<BuildResult, bool>(BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest), true);
```

I'm a bit at a loss because these information seems contradictory. I couldn't find any help online either.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?